# showing save dialogue with filechooseIconView kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm doing a quick drawing app as my first kivy project, and what I'm trying to currently do is to have i so I can display and select the directory the user selects using FileChooser. However, I've hit a wall where when you go through the user directory, it duplicates the files and moves on. Below is a before and after of what I mean. Notice the directories of the previous shifting to the next after I selected my Windows directory,

[image: Before Directory]

[image: After Directory]

I'm wondering if anyone would have an idea why this is happening. Anything helps, I've just been very stuck. Below is my code for the saving portion of my personal project,

```
class BottomCanvasLayout(Widget):

    def exitPopUp(self):
        self._popup.dismiss()

    def showSave(self):
        content = SaveDialog(save=self.save_press, cancel=self.exitPopUp)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Save file", content=content, size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

class SaveDialog(FloatLayout):
    save = ObjectProperty(None)
    filename = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)



kv = Builder.load_file("mydrawing.kv")

class MyDrawingApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyDrawingApp().run()

#mydrawing.kv
<SaveDialog>:
    id: save_dialog
    filename: filename

    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"

        #FileChooserListView:
        FileChooserIconView:
            id: filechooser

        TextInput:
            id: filename
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            multiline: False

       BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.cancel()

            Button:
                text: "Save"
```

Comment: There may be an issue with double loading the `mydrawing.kv` file. Since it is named correctly, it will get loaded automatically, and you are also loading it explicitly. To see if this is the problem, just change the name of your `kv` file.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Sir, you are a life saver, I truly appreciate this. It works now, thank you